# Using Curl in a Bash script to check if a site is up

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to incorporate a way to check if a site has loaded inside Tomcat when I run my startup script and have it tell me when Tomcat has fully started. This is what I have so far. When I run the `curl` command solo it works fine and shows no data if Tomcat `isweb` is running. But for some reason if I run it in this loop it continues to loop no matter if it finds anything or not. Any ideas?

```
until [ "(curl --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 1 -I http://localhost | grep 'isweb')" != "" ];
do
  echo --- Tomcat is starting, please wait...
  sleep 10
done
echo -e "\e[00;32mApplications are ready!\e[00m"
```

Comment: Here is the what I ended up doing. `#!/bin/bash
until [ "$(curl --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 1 -I http://localhost/isweb | grep 'isweb')" ];
do
echo -e "\e[00;33mTomcat is starting, please wait.........................`date '+%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S'`\e[00m"
  sleep 5
done
echo -e "\e[00;32mApplications are loaded!\e[00m"
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) don't produce the output of the command, they preserve the literal value of the characters with the exception of some special characters. What's happening in your script that you're comparing the string `"(curl --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 1 -I http://localhost | grep 'isweb')"` with an empty string, and that will never be `true`.

If you enclose the commands in backticks (`) instead, Bash will execute the command and evaluate its output, producing the result you need.

But an even better and more modern POSIX-compliant way to do it in Bash would be to use a subshell with the `$(...)` syntax, `$(curl --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 1 -I http://localhost | grep 'isweb')` in your case. You can read about the advantages of the subshell over backticks [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

This is what your script will look like then:

```
until [ "$(curl --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 1 -I http://localhost | grep 'isweb')" ];
do
  echo --- Tomcat is starting, please wait...
  sleep 10
done
```

Note that for `[` to work correctly, you will need to enclose the `$(...)` syntax in double quotes, because `[`is simply shorthand for the `test` command and interprets commands with spaces as multiple arguments. The double quotes help preserve the ouput as one argument (if you have read the contents of the link in the beginning, you would know that variables denoted with `$` are interpreted). You also don't need the comparison operator, if the output is empty, it will be evaluated as `false`.

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but a command substitution inside square brackets is still a clumsy newbie antipattern.  Also, you lack a space before the closing square bracket.  The purpose of `if` is to run a command and examine its success code, so you should just do that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I ended up using this but had to modify http://localhost to be http://localhost/isweb for it to work. Here is my entire code. `info(){
until [ "$(curl --silent --show-error --connect-timeout 1 -I http://localhost/isweb | grep 'isweb')" ];
do
echo -e "\e[00;33mTomcat is starting, please wait.........................`date '+%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M:%S'`\e[00m"
  sleep 1
done
echo -e "\e[00;32mApplications are loaded!\e[00m"
          
}`

Comment: I added info to my start command on tomcat init script and now it works as desired. `start() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo -e "\e[00;31mTomcat is already running (pid: $pid)\e[00m"
  else
    # Start tomcat
    echo -e "\e[00;32mStarting tomcat\e[00m"
    #ulimit -n 100000
    #umask 007
    #/bin/su -p -s /bin/sh $TOMCAT_USER
        if [ `user_exists $TOMCAT_USER` = "1" ]
        then
                /bin/su $TOMCAT_USER -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        else
                sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        fi
        info
  status
  fi
  return 0
}`

Answer (score 3):

You probably already know that you're missing the `$` for the command substitution inside `until`'s condition.

But aside from that, I would handle this a little differently.

The `until` or `while` command simply executes a command as its "condition". In many cases, the command is `[` (a.k.a. /bin/test) or `[[` (a built-in in bash).  But the evaluation of whether or not a test passes is whether its exit value is zero or non-zero. And grep will return 0 (success) if it finds something or non-zero (fail) if it does not.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a curl_opts=()
curl_opts+=(-silent)
curl_opts+=(--show-error)
curl_opts+=("--connect-timeout 1")
curl_opts+=(-I)

start=$(date '+%s')

until curl "${curl_opts[@]}" http://localhost | grep -q 'isweb'; do
  date '+[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] --- Tomcat is starting, please wait...'
  sleep 10
done

dur=$(($(date '+%s') - start))

echo -e "\e[00;32mApplications are ready! ($dur second delay)\e[00m"
```

A few things to note...

- I moved curl options into an array. For something like curl, which has a gazillion options, this can really help with command line management.
- Added a timer, using the `$start` and `$dur` variables. You don't really need `$dur`, but using a variable here makes things easier to read.
- Added a date stamp to your "please wait" message. You might even want to recalculate `$dur` to include in this message, in case Tomcat takes longer than expected to start.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I ended up using the other answer. I tested yours and it continued to loop even when tomcat was running. Maybe I was missing something.

Comment: @David -- No worries -- Any code in an answer here must be considered an *example*. The goal is to help you learn how to improve your own script, not to give you a packaged product that you don't have to think about. With any luck, my answer also helped you learn about using arrays for arguments, expanding the format of the `date` command, and improving how you handle conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the *output* of the curl command pipe in order to compare it to "". For this, you need to enclose the curl pipe in backquotes rather than double quotes.